# How to automatically set a random string ID in Laravel when a user registers

Tags: laravel

I would like to set a unique random string (str_random) as the user id automatically when the user is registered.

Where do I put the code?

**`'id' => str_random(32);`**

I thought it should go in the **User.php** (model).

Comment: To anyone coming here from Google, like me: *do not use str_random for ID generation*, you *will* run into collusions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually solved the question myself by doing the following. I am not sure whether this is the best practice or not.

In **UsersController.php**

```
public function store()
    {
        $data = Input::all();

        $data['id'] = str_random(32); // THIS IS THE LINE

        $validator = Validator::make($data = Input::all(), User::$rules);
        if ($validator->fails())
        {
            return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
        }
        User::create($data);
        return Redirect::route('users.index');
    }
```

Comment: This might result in duplicate ids and fail?

Answer (score 5):

You could do this in your model:

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::creating(function($table)
    {
        $table->id = str_random(32);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the `creating` eloquent event to hijack the creation of the User object and set your random id there.

More information: http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#model-events

Comment: Where does this go? Can I not put it on the User.php model?

Comment: You can... In the boot method for example. Look for `Setting A Model Boot Method` in the documentation I linked.